# How to limit file choice to a single directory?

Tags: c++, linux, file, dialog, wxwidgets

I am working with wxWidgets 2.9.3 in Arch Linux on a C++ project where the finished program will run in a "kiosk mode", so the user should not be able to access or even see the underlying system files. I still need to let the user open and save files on USB drives that he might connect. I have set it up so that USB drives are automatically mounted on /media.

So what I need is a file-picking dialog where I can limit the choice to files and folders in the /media directory. Does such a thing exist, or do I have to make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wxFileDialog** does not have that feature.
If I were you I would build a simple dialog like this:

[image: custom file dialog]

Comment: Making my own does indeed seem to be the only solution. It'd have to be able to explore subfolders, so a bit more complex than the above, perhaps, but yes.